# Update Tweets not working online

Tags: html, twitter

I have a strange issue using the Twitter "update tweets" widget.
I set all the settings needed in the twitter account under **Settings -> Widgets -> Create new -> Enter settings** and copied the HTML provide:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/runegreen" data-widget-id="278794989184618498">Tweets by @runegreen</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Now this works just fine LOCALLY, it's strange that when I look at the website online because it only displays a text saying **Tweets by @runegreen**

But locally it shows the following:

[image]

All files are uploaded so I'm really wondering what could go wrong.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Anything in the JavaScript error console? Are all scripts correctly loaded (look in the browser's dev tools)?

Comment: Juhana, I wasn't aware of being able to view javascript errors in the console - I did this and was told the domain was the problem. Right now, the website is on a test-server and the domain I inserted was the "real server" - that caused the problem. Thank you for this tip! Problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Juhana gave me a tip to view the Console in my browsers dev tool and see if there was a problem.

The problem was:

- In Twitters widget settings you can enter a domain.
- The domain I entered was the real domain (eg.: www.mywebsite.com)
- But for now, the site is on a test server (eg.:
  www.mywebsite.testserver.com)
- So I had to enter the test server link inside the widget settings on
  twitters website.

Problem solved :)